# cannot connect via 8333 port on website

Tags: bitcoin-core

MY bitcoind is on: `http://207.12.89.181/` yet I cannot connect via any port, I've tried 8333 and 8332 any reason why? it's a ubuntu server. Im using that server to connect to from another server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `rpcallowip` setting to your `bitcoind.conf` file.

You can use a single IP or allow all. for example

`rcpallowip=192.168.0.2`

or

`rcpallowip=*`

Comment: I don't know where my conf file is, I'm using putty and ssh.

Comment: @user3162803 config file is at ``~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf``